# How to change tab order within one control (div) - html

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I have a composite control which consists of two different parts - react-based and d3-based. The resulted tab order is incorrect. I can fix it using tabindex attributes but this collides with tab order of overall page.

Is there a way to fix tab order only under some  element in a way it would not affect overall tab order?

**Update (providing example)**: The below control (outlined in blue) has 4 focusable elements. Right now the tab order is not correct. It follows how elements are defined in DOM. Changing the order of elements is tricky (for instance, d3.brush adds brush elements in opposite order).

Using tab index solves the problem in the control but it breaks the tab order for the whole page.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample, so that we can better understand what you are describing?

Comment: Updated & added example.

Comment: It's weird to see a flagship Microsoft Azure product getting help here.

Comment: I'm glad the product was named a flagship product, I hope it is useful! :)

Asking questions here pursues two goals - one is to get an advice from the expert (even though we can be considered experts in usage of a particular technology, nobody knows everything). Another goal was to bring more attention to accessibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using tabindex with positive values is a bad idea as a screenreader will still read the page using the DOM order, and having a different order for keyboard navigation would be very disturbing.

In terms of accessibility you should have an equivalence between : visual order (=CSS order), screenreader reading order (=DOM order), and keyboard order.

In your case, the best solution is to invert the DOM order to match the visual order.

You can also inhibit the links in the tab order (by setting `tabindex=-1`) and give alternative accessible controls.